# Why can't my web application access my .properties file

Tags: java, web-applications, configuration-files

I have created a .properties file for several configurations that I need for my web application to run properly. I created a testing method for accessing this file and its properties and couldn't get it to work either. In both my web app class and my testing method I get the same null pointer exception, which takes you through a list of factory classes and control classes but the problem all lies in the same method here is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at com.RichardDavy42.properties.Configure.getProperty(Configure.java:56)
at com.secureautodata.business.data.CustomerFactory.fetchCustomer(CustomerFactory.java:44)
at com.secureautodata.business.data.LeadAssembly.assembleLead(LeadAssembly.java:42)
at com.secureautodata.control.DirectoryAssistance.doPost(DirectoryAssistance.java:396)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The Configure.java is the class that contains my getProperties method with a simple bit of code like so:

```
    /**
 * Calls on the properties file to fetch the properties that 
 * you are looking for, for use in your application.
 * @param propertyName
 * @return
 */
public static String getProperty(String nof, String propertyName){
    String property = "";

    Properties props = new Properties();

    try (InputStream input = Configure.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(nof)){

        props.load(input);
        property = props.getProperty(propertyName);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("There was an Error retrieving your data");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return property;
}
```

I have tried calling this file several times with different methods of calling the file such as:

```
System.out.println("Configure Properties property retrieval " + Configure.getProperty("/WebAppRootFolder/config.properties", "enc1"));

System.out.println("Configure Properties property retrieval " + Configure.getProperty("WebAppRootFolder/config.properties", "enc1"));

System.out.println("Configure Properties property retrieval " + Configure.getProperty("/config.properties", "enc1"));

System.out.println("Configure Properties property retrieval " + Configure.getProperty("config.properties", "enc1"));
```

All of these give me the same exception referring back to the getProperty method so I thought maybe my file was empty I opened my file and found that it was not, containing this information:

```
#Mon Jan 19 13:32:58 EST 2015
enc2=aijf3w97fhfieu4bfqg8o34fibagc48wfbhhba4
enc1=sldhnf9aw7h3un429q8anf9478wfi9a7hw49hiu
```

I cal this method the same anywhere that it is referenced so I have tried this on all levels.

The file structure is such:

```
WebAppRootFolder
|
|_src
|_TomcatLibrary
|_JUnitLibrary
|_Maven
|_Referenced
|_JRE
|_build
|_docs
|_target
|_webcontent
|_config.properties <--- config.properties in root folder
|_javadoc.xml
|_LICENSE
|_pom.xml
|_README.md
```

The only thing that I can think of is that the PropertiesConfiguration where the Configure class is located is a jar from an earlier project that I created and maybe it is trying to find the file within itself, but I am not sure that this would be the case.

In case it is helpful (in this situation I am not sure that it is because I am getting the same error in a main method as I am everywhere else) this is the flow of the original method call:

```
User calls request on a file -->
Servlet Instantiates Factory Class -->
Factory method makes use of Config.getProperty() During file call-->
Factory method Creates Object and returns the Object to the User --X
```

Thank you guys for your help in advance.

Comment: It looks like a deployment problem. Can you move that config file into WEB-INF directory most probably located in webcontent dir.Then try        Configure.getProperty("/WEB-INF/config.properties", "enc1"));

Comment: @cool Same error as the first

Comment: can you move that file near your Configure class and use it just Configure.getProperty("config.properties", "enc1")); Before doing that can you make sure that config.properties deployed to deploy directory ? Most probably it is not deployed to tomcat. I also can't understand the structure you shared. Is that a maven project ? If so where is src/main/java etc.

Comment: @cool interestingly enough you were correct, but I am not sure that I did it the way that you were expecting. The jar file that I packaged did not contain the properties file, so... I moved the .properties file into the PropertiesConfiguration project that I had built for my other project and redeployed the jar. I then placed that jar in my Tomcat/Lib directory and ran the program again and it worked like a charm. So it goes without saying that I should have tried my original gut feeling when I thought of it and placed the .properties file in my jar before deploying it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed the "src" at the top. If it is a maven project you should put that file into src/main/resources directory to be deployed.

Comment: @cool The project configuration was set up by eclipse when I converted it into a maven project, I haven't had any issues out of it in regards to the maven resources. I think that when the project is bottled up into the .war file on export eclipse takes care of the maven details for me. But I appreciate the insight and will definitely use it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I had some assistance from @cool in a series of comments that we shared so here goes:

The Configure.getProperties() method that I was using was part of a jar file that I had created in an earlier project. Therefore every time that the method was called it was looking for the .properties file within that jar file. To find this error I moved the .properties file into the previous project and redeployed the jar file. After doing so I tested my current project again and viola like a charm it worked.

So if in the event that in the future you happen to build a project that requires a jar file, and that jar file requires the calling of a .properties file to run the application you are building. The .properties file must be deployed with the jar file, or at the very least you must have a way to get into that project from within your current application.

I hope this helps square up the question.